# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2 when favoriting an item

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm making a favorites list viewer for my application. Basically, on the listview there will be a trailing containing a heart icon which will then add the designated item to the favorite menu. Here is the code for said action

```
title: Text(displayJournal[index].journalTitle!),
              trailing: journal_list[index].status == false
              ? IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    favoriteBloc.addItems(JournalModel(
                      id: journal_list[index].id,
                      journalTitle: journal_list[index].journalTitle,
                      journalReleaseYear: journal_list[index].journalReleaseYear,
                      author: journal_list[index].author,
                      topic: journal_list[index].topic,
                      fileLocation: journal_list[index].fileLocation,
                      status: journal_list[index].status,
                      ));
                      
                      setState(() {
                      journal_list[index].status = true;
                    });
                  }, 
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border))  
              : IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                    favoriteBloc.removeItems(favoriteBloc.items[index]);

                      setState(() {
                      journal_list[index].status = false;
                    });
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
                color: Colors.red,
                ),
```

Here is the code on the favorite menu, essentially is the same thing but it's just the delete function

```
title: Text(favoriteBloc.items[index].journalTitle!),
            trailing: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                favoriteBloc.removeItems(favoriteBloc.items[index]);

                 setState(() {
                  journal_list[index].status = false;
                  });
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete)
            ),
```

Since I'm using provider, i also have a `favorites_provider.dart`. Below is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aplikasi_jurnal_mobile/models/journals.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class FavoriteBloc with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;
  List<JournalModel> items = [];

  bool get isEmpty => items.isEmpty;

  void addItems(JournalModel data) {
    items.add(data);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeItems(JournalModel data) {
    items.remove(data);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get count {
    return _count;
  }

  List<JournalModel> get itemsList {
    return items;
  }
}
```

Also, here is the model structure of the item

```
class JournalModel{
  String? id;
  String? journalTitle;
  int? journalReleaseYear;
  String? author;
  String? topic;
  String? fileLocation;
  bool status;

JournalModel({
  this.id,
   this.journalTitle,
   this.journalReleaseYear,
   this.author,
   this.topic,
   this.fileLocation,
   this.status = false
  });
}
```

So essentially, what's supposed to happen is that if i press the heart icon it will change the state of the item's `is_favorited` to true, make the item appear at the favorite menu and turn the icon color to red. And if i press it again it would set it to false, remove the item from the favorite menu and make the icon grey again.

And it works, but there is a bit of a problem. If i favorite an item sequentially, it would work no problem and i can delete it and the state would reset. However, if i were to favorite a random item on the list, the favorite button would be stuck on the "favorited" state.

The same thing would happen if i were to delete the item from the favorite menu. If i remove an item in the middle of the list, the bottom one would be stuck on the favorite state and i have to reset the whole thing if that happens.

If i look at the console, it would throw the error stated in the topic title above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that the problem has been resolved. Basically, i declared the wrong variable.

Instead of:

```
title: Text(favoriteBloc.items[index].journalTitle!),
            trailing: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                favoriteBloc.removeItems(favoriteBloc.items[index]);

                 setState(() {
                  journal_list[index].status = false;
                  });
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete)
            ),
```

It should have been

```
title: Text(favoriteBloc.items[index].journalTitle!),
            trailing: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                favoriteBloc.removeItems(favoriteBloc.items[index]);

                 setState(() {
                  favoriteBloc.items[index].status = false;
                  });
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete)
            ),
```

Now it works perfectly.